# Google Fonts Not being applied. I am trying to apply Google Fonts to a text inside a container

Tags: html, css

Hey i just started using HTML. I have been trying to apply google fonts to my website but i dont think they seem to be applying. Here is my script. I am trying to apple the fonts to the .middlescreen container. I tried both the standard method and the import method but both didnt seem to be working

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap');
<style>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


   



.middleScreen {
position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
   width : 100px ;
   height : 100px ;
   background-color : orange ; 
    margin-top: -50px; /* = - 1/2 of the height*/
    margin-left: -50px; /* = - 1/2 of the width*/
    text-align: center;
}

div.middlescreen p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
</style>
```

```html
<div class="middleScreen">
<p><font color="white">Welcome to the </font></p>
<p><font color="white">New Home</font></p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use in head section this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .middleScreen {
        position:absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width : 100px ;
        height : 100px ;
        background-color : orange ; 
        margin-top: -50px; /* = - 1/2 of the height*/
        margin-left: -50px; /* = - 1/2 of the width*/
        text-align: center;
    }

    .middleScreen p {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="middleScreen">
    <p>Welcome to the</p>
    <p>New Home</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```